# Cannot install old iOS "iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support" to Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to install older iOS SDK to Xcode 4.2.
As I see several pages talking about this, so I tried common step to achieve this.

**[Menu] Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support > Install**

Then I hit the following error.

> The data couldn't be  read because it has been corrupted.

Same thing happens with "iOS 3.0 - 3.2.2 Device Debugging Support"

I reinstalled Xcode, still have same error.

Xcode installer I have is 4.2 for Snow Leopard, Posted Date: October 12, 2011. - Latest one we can download from iOS Dev Center as of December 22nd 2011.

Did anyone experienced same issue?

Appreciate any advices. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just tried that (almost the same config as yours, my xcode is 4.2 Build 4C199, installed on Oct 15 2011), and both packages install without error.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I will see any other stuff I can try then.

Comment: Hi again, my Xcode 4.2 build is 4C199 too. Reboot machine, redownload dmg, reinstalling did not work. Do you know where "iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support" file is located? I'd like to check whether the data is really corrupted.

Comment: I hoped that the url was put into some plist, but it's not. You need to look at the network traffic to get the url. Maybe older versions of xcode help you too. You can get them from http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.1.3.3.1

Comment: This is horrific. It's downloading super fast, but using 60-100% CPU. It shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for your comments. I could finally solve this problem by manually installing those files downloaded from adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by manually installing files of 'iOS 4.0 - 4.1 Device Debugging Support' and 'iOS 3.0 - 3.2.2 Device Debugging Support' downloaded from adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools, and installed in Macintosh HD/Developer.

e.g. Macintosh HD/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0

Many thanks,

Nanako